# $T:V \to V$ be a unitary, self conjugated, Prove: exists a subspace $W$: $T(v) = v''-v', v = v'+v'', v' \in W, v'' \in W^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a unitary inner product space with finite dimension.

Let $T:V \to V$ be a unitary $(T^*T=TT^*=I)$, adjoint $(T^*=T)$ linear transformation.

Prove that exists a subspace for $V$ call it $W$ such that:

$$
T(v) = v''-v'
$$

For all $v \in V$ which satisfies: $v = v'+v''$, $v' \in W, v'' \in W^{\perp}$

I wrote a $2$ pages answer, i think what i wrote is not good and very complicated, can someone direct me to a more simple answer?

Comment: By unitary finite space I assume you mean a finite dimensional inner product space, and by "self conjugated" do you mean self adjoint or just $T=\overline{T}$?

Comment: @Dave I tried to correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From unitary and self adjoint we deduce that the eigenvalues of $T$ belong to $\{1,-1\}$. Indeed, one way to see this is that unitary operators have eigenvalues in the unit circle in $\mathbb C$, and self adjoint operators have real eigenvalues. Another way is that unitary implies $TT^*=I$ and self adjoint means $T=T^*$, so $T^2-I=0$ and thus the eigenvalues must satisfy $\lambda^2-1=0$.

Now let $W$ be the $-1$-eigenspace of $T$. Since $T$ is diagonalizable, the eigenspaces are orthogonal and direct sum to all of $V$, so we have that $W^\perp$ is the $1$-eigenspace of $T$.

I'll let you bring it all together.

Comment: Ok so that explain $V = W \oplus W^{\perp}$ but how did they get to this $T(v) = v''-v'$ transformation?

Comment: Use the eigenvalue/eigenvector definition (and linearity)

Comment: $T(v) = T(v'+v'') = T(v') + T(v'') = v'+(-)v'' = v'+v''$ Thank you.